# How to finish executing an event in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

**Response** is called to send a response to the client. Only after the call, the execution of the handler continues

```
socket.on('text-sticker', async (data, response) => {
    await connection.query("...", [
        data.id,
        socket.user_id
    ])
        .then(result => {
            if (result[0][0].my == 0) {
                response({
                    status: 0
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return response({
                status: 0,
                err: err
            });
        });
```

Comment: Чего? Вопрос непонятен. Какое ожидаемое поведение и какое наблюдаемое?

Comment: @Darth Фух, православные

Ожидаемое предполагается, что после вызова колбэка response работа обработчика  on завершиться, однако и ответ возвращается, и обработчик продолжает выполняться. Например, в коде выше идет какая-то проверка, в случае ошибки должен отправиться ответ со статусом 0 и все. Однако происходит выполнение кода, который находится ниже (тут не указан)

Comment: Вообще тут не принято не на английском, заходи на ruSO - там на такие вопросы тебе легко ответят. А тут имеет смысл морочится, если ты язык хочешь подтянуть или если у тебя реально сложный вопрос, на который на ruSO не смогли ответить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const connection_query = () => 
  new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(rej, 1000));

const response = data => console.log('response', data);


// Было:
window.addEventListener('text-sticker', async () => {  
  await connection_query()
      .then(result => {})
      .catch(err => {
          // Здесь return прерывает выполнение обработчика catch.
          // выполнение обработчика text-sticker продолжается
          // async и await здесь лишние
          return response({status: 1});
      });
  console.log('Выполнение неуказанного кода..');
});

// How to finish executing:
window.addEventListener('text-sticker', async () => {
    try {
      const result = await connection_query();
      // if(result) ....
    } catch(err) {
      // Здесь return прервет выполнение обработчика text-stiker
      return response({status: 2});
    }       
    console.log('Выполнение неуказанного кода..');
});


window.dispatchEvent(new Event("text-sticker"));
```